# Need to parse dynamic HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>>

Tags: android, json, parsing, hashmap

I am parsing a json and than i need to populate the values on the graph, the response which i am getting as below

```
 {
 "message": "Successful.",
 "data": {
 "stats": {
  "Total Transactions": 1,
  "Today Transactions": 0,
  "Today Pending Transactions": 0,
  "Payment links created": 2,
  "Api payments": 0
},
"otherData": {
  "countiesData": {
    "2021": {
      "US": 1
    }
  },
  "transactionTypesData": {
    "2021": {
      "PAYMENT_LINK": 1
    }
  },
  "graphData": {
    "2021": {
      "SUCCESS": {
        "1": 0,
        "2": 0,
        "3": 0,
        "4": 0,
        "5": 0,
        "6": 0,
        "7": 0,
        "8": 0,
        "9": 1,
        "10": 0,
        "11": 0,
        "12": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "currentMoth": 3200,
  "preMonthAvr": 3200
}
},
"code": 200,
"accessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9."
}
```

I have created the model data for graphData within otherData.

```
data class OtherData(
    var countiesData : Any,
    var transactionTypesData: Any,
    var graphData : HashMap<String,HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>>

)
```

i got the year with in graphData by these lines but i am unable to get other values within year object.

```
it.data.data.otherData.graphData.let { graphYear->
                        if (graphYear.isNotEmpty()){
                            tvYearForRevenueReport.text = graphYear.keys.elementAt(0)
                            tvFirstGraphLabel.text = graphYear.getValue(graphYear.keys.elementAt(0))   // giving error at this line 
                        }
                    }
```

so my question is what i am doing it is the best way to do it? if it is than how, and if there is any work around will be glad to hear.

Comment: Isn't graphData: HashMap<String,HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Int>>>
Also, what is the error you receive?

Comment: doesn't matter i can take recast string into Int

Comment: Can you your parsing line? Gson/JSONObject calls?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) I was able to parse your JSON:

Creating a Data class:

```
data class Data(
    val data: InnerData
)
```

And an InnerData class:

```
data class InnerData(
    val otherData: OtherData
)
```

And using your OtherData class:

```
data class OtherData(
    var countiesData : Any,
    var transactionTypesData: Any,
    var graphData : HashMap<String,HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>>
)
```

Calling Gson to parse the JSON input:

```
val parsed = Gson().fromJson(json, Data::class.java)
```

I've used your JSON as an input and everything was working as expected.